# Propositional logic- consistency

Tags: logic

> No more than one of the following statements is true:
>
> for every $a$,
> $X\cup \{a\}$  is consistent
> or $X\cup \{\neg a\}$ is consistent
>
> Does this imply that $X$ is consistent?

I tried to solve this question, the answer is that no more than 1 statement is true for X to be consistent.
Obviously if both are true, X is incositent since there is no assignment that satisfies both.

It is possible for 1 of the statements to be true and X be consistent.

But is is possible that no sentence is true and X is consistent?
in more detail, is it possible the X is consistent, but $\displaystyle X\cup \{a\} \ $ is inconsistent AND $\displaystyle X\cup \{\neg a\} \ $ is inconsistent?

The questtion comes from a recent Test in my university, it was probably taken from the Technion.

Comment: With my TeX user hat on, I hope you never, ever write an article using what you did here to format material. `$  $` is for mathematics,  not italics.

Comment: Thanks, I just started learning how to write maths.

What led me to this specific question is a question from an examp I have, that states that if X is consistent no more than 1 of the following statements are true.

The incorrect answer was 'exactly 1 statement is true', which is what I think to be true.

Comment: I am a student, this is a question in Propositional Logic.
The example came from my recent Test, it was probably taken from the Technion in israel.
I'll edit my post to draw more respones. thanks

Comment: One way to see why this is true is that any theory that is consistent must have a model. In such model either $a$ or $\neg a$ so one of the two must be consistent with $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is rather straight forward and doesn't require too much background knowledge. There are two rule that are needed for the proof. We use the following notation $X\vdash a$ means that $a$ can be proved using assumptions in $X$. By $\bot$ we mean a contradiction which is any sentence of the form $a\wedge \neg a$. A theory or collection of propositions $X$ is inconsistent if $X\vdash \bot$.

The first is if for a collection of sentences $X$ we have $X\vdash a$ and $X\vdash b$ then $X\vdash a\wedge b$ or rather if I can prove $a$ from $X$ and $b $ from $X$ I can prove $a$ and $b$ from $X$.

The second is that if $X\cup \{a\}\vdash \bot$ then $X\vdash \neg a$

For the proof we suppose that both $X\cup \{a\}$ and $X\cup \{\neg a\}$ are inconsistent, that means $X\cup \{a\}\vdash \bot$ and $X\cup \{\neg a\}\vdash \bot$ using the second rule we get $X\vdash a$ and $X\vdash \neg a$ and using the first rule we get $X\vdash a\wedge \neg a$. But this is absurd as it would mean $X$ is inconsistent.

Comment: To my taste, you show that if $X$ is consistent, then for every $a$, either $X\cup\{a\}$ or $X\cup\{\neg a\}$ is consistent, which is not an answer to OP's question.

Comment: OP asks "in more detail, is it possible the X is consistent, but $X\cup\{a\}$ is inconsistent AND $X\cup\{\neg a\}$  is inconsistent". I show this cannot be the case since if $X$ is consistent then $X\cup \{a\}$ or $X\cup \{\neg a\}$ must be consistent. @MadHatter

Comment: Ah, OK. I did not notice this fragment of the question.